# How to differentiate each iterated item in JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl, servlet-3.0

I have following code, backend are my servlets, and it successfully iterator display the table row, My question is, how to differentiate each iterated tr(table row) like `id` in such iterator stuffs in jstl?

PS: I just want use Taglib (JSTL), scriptlets (those <% %> things) answers will not acceptable, thanks :)

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>    
<c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
    <tr>
        <td>${item.id}</td>
        <td>${item.name}</td>
        <td>${item.price}</td>
        <td>${item.time}</td>
        <td>${item.location}</td>
        <td>${item.url}</td>
        <td>${item.description}</td>
        <td><a class="button remove">remove</a></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: `<tr id="${item.id}">` ?

Comment: @JB Nizet ya, it works..i'm stupid, lol